# Помогите с задачей на CodeWars

Tags: c++

Помогите пожалуйста. У меня есть маленький опыт в программирование, и я изучаю c++. Я накопил достаточный опыт, чтобы решать задачи на CodeWars.  И тут такая проблема, нужно написать функцию которое возвращает букву взаимности от чисел. Например, я ввел в функцию 90 95 93, тогда она возвращает A, или 54 57 51, тогда она возвращает F. Ну код я проверил. и он работает нормально. Но когда я вставляю код в Solution, и нажимаю кнопку Attempt, то он выдает Test Results: GradeBook. Что делать я не знаю. Вот эта задача: https://www.codewars.com/kata/55cbd4ba903825f7970000f5/train/cpp

```
using namespace std;

char getGrade(int a, int b, int c) {
    if(a>=90 && b>90 && c<=100){
        cout << "A";
    }
    else if(a>=80 && b>80 && c<=90){
        cout << "B";
    }
    else if(a>=70 && b>70 && c<=80){
        cout << "C";
    }
    else if(a>=60 && b>60 && c<=70){
        cout << "D";
    }
    else if(a>=0 && b>0 && c<=60){
        cout << "F";
    }
}
```

Comment: надо возвращать, а не выводить результат

Comment: да и логика у вас неправильная. берем значение из тестов 70, 70, 100. У вас ничего не выводит, а должно быть B

Comment: берем 70, 70, 70 у вас выводит D, а должно C

Comment: В условии написано, что нужно выводить среднее арифметическое. Складываешь три числа и делишь на три. Только после этого смотришь, в какой  диапазон попал результат.

Answer (score 0):

Читайте внимательней условие задачи

```
char getGrade(int a, int b, int c) {
      // your code here
      int val = (a + b + c) / 3;

      if(val >= 90 && val <= 100 ) {
        return 'A';
      }
      if(val >= 80 && val < 90) {
        return 'B';
      }
      if(val >= 70 && val < 80) {
        return 'C';
      }
      if(val >= 60 && val < 70) {
        return 'D';
      }
      if(val >= 0 && val < 60) {
        return 'F';
      }

      return '0';

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, нужно не выводить результат, а возвращать.
Во-вторых, почему просто не найти среднее значение и не посмотреть входит ли оно в нужный диапазон?

```
char getGrade(int a, int b, int c) {
    int avg = (a + b + c) / 3;
    if(90 <= avg  && avg <= 100) // 90 <= score <= 100
        return 'A';
    else if(80 <= avg  && avg <= 90) // 80 <= score < 90
        return 'B';
    else if(70 <= avg  && avg <= 80) // 70 <= score < 80
        return 'C';
    else if(60 <= avg  && avg <= 70) // 60 <= score < 70
        return 'D';
    else if(0 <= avg  && avg <= 60) // 0 <= score < 60
        return 'F';

    return 'F';
}
```